# Joomla override category layout

Tags: php, joomla

I'm trying to build a new layout for category blog post using a masonry layout for displaying the blog posts preview.

I've created 3 files: bloglayoutalternativo.php, bloglayoutalternativo.xml and bloglayoutalternativo_item.php

I've creted the masonry code inside the blogalternative.php like this:

```
<div itemprop="blogPost" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
    <div class="event-container">
        <ul class="event-main-box clearfix<?php echo $moduleclass_sfx; ?>">
            <?php
                $i = 0;

                foreach ($this->items as $key => &$item) {
                    if($i%2 == 0)
                    {
                        $class = 'item col-xs-6 col-md-4';
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $class = 'item col-xs-6 col-md-8';
                    }
                    $i++;
                ?>
                <li class="<?php echo $class; ?>" itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/BlogPosting">
                    <figure>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->link; ?>" class="more-details" itemprop="url">
                            <img src="<?php echo json_decode($item->images)->image_intro; ?>" alt="<?php echo $item->title; ?>"/>
                        </a>
                        <figcaption>
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->link; ?>" itemprop="url">
                                <span class="title-box">
                                    <span class="title" itemprop="name"><?php echo $item->title; ?></span>
                                    <span class="sub-title"><?php echo $item->category_title; ?></span>
                                </span>
                                <span class="desc">
                                    <?php echo substr(strip_tags($item->introtext),0,75);?><?php echo '...' ?>
                                </span>
                            </a>
                        </figcaption>
                    </figure>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

The masonry view is correctly displayed in my blog view anyway I'm not able to let work the links to each article.

I got this error: /
 **Notice**:  Undefined property: ContentViewCategory::$link in **/home/dfgdfgdfg/mysite/templates/mytemplate/html/com_content/category/bloglayoutalternativo.php** on line **127**

What should I do?